# What is the best way to play inaudible sound?

Tags: speakers

I have a speaker - JBL Charge - that auto turn off after 10 minutes if it doesn't receive any audio signal. I wish to keep it always on but there is no settings for this.

The only possible way I can see would be to send some inaudible audio input so that it stays on without producing any noise. I'm thinking about sending ultrasonic. Is there a better way ?

Comment: Could you specify speaker model?

Comment: @MichaelHansenBuur speaker is JBL Charge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the speaker model and how it implements audio detection in the auto turn off mechanism.

If it is a digitally connected speaker it may be enough playing a wavefile with silence in it.

If it is an analog connection, silence is detected, and signals below a certain level is considered "silent". In that case you need to send something just above the threshold. I'd go with a very low frequency impulse, since it can hold a lot of energy and thereby is more likely to go over the threshold.

Try a sine at 5-10 Hz with no attack and soft release.

About the ultrasonic idea: Your system is most likely not able to reproduce true ultrasonic ranges. At best you may be able to trigger it using 15 - 20 KHz, which you or your guests may hear.